# Git: Pulling and merging branch into Master

Tags: git, github, merge

So far I have used Git individually and first time I am using as a team. I am facing an issue: There is a `master` repo which contains 2 branches; `dev1` and `dev2`. I have been assigned to review Code of `dev1` and merge into `master`.

Now In order to view code or running it I want to set his branch on local machine. How do I pull all of his branch data very first time so that I could have his folders on machine and how later I could pull his changes from his branch.

Later how do I merge branch `dev1` into `master`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using github? You tagged github which would imply a pull request type review approach, but your question states that you have master and 2 branches within the same repo. Basically, can you clarify if you have a forked repo looking to do pull requests or a single repo with multiple branches and a manual review process?

Comment: *There is a master repo which contains 2 branches* do you mean you have a **remote** repo with **3** branches: `master`, `dev1` and `dev2`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes Remote Github repo

Answer (score 0):

If you not already have a clone of the remote repo:

```
git clone <remote repo url from GitHub>
cd <repo>
```

Fetch all remote branches from remote repo:

```
git fetch origin
```

Checkout remote branch 'dev1':

```
git checkout dev1
```

Review and run the code as you see fit.

If you have privileges (on GitHub) to push to 'origin:master' you should be able to merge 'master' with 'dev1' and push the updated 'master':

```
git checkout master
git merge dev1
git push origin master
```

If you do not have privileges to update remote 'origin:master' you can issue a pull-request (on GitHub).

Comment: `git clone..` So I clone(which suppose to clone master), checkout from `dev1` branch; checkout master for any updated thing on `master`; merge and then push into `master`. Is it like that?

Comment: Don't forget `git fetch origin` to fetch branches `dev1` and `dev2` from origin.

Comment: Can you recommend some good resource to learn GIT/Guthub for multiple teams? I want to learn that when it cloned master. Which command pulled data from a certain branch too.

Comment: @Volatil3, https://git-scm.com can be god start, I can recomend reading "Pro Git" by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub (available for free at https://git-scm.com/book). Also Github and Atlasian have god tutorials (even if they are biased toward their own product).